# Не могу подключиться по External IP

Tags: jenkins, google-cloud

Зарегался на google cloud,поставил виртуалку,установил jenkins,проверил в статусах что служба работала,она и работает,добавил firewall rule для tcp:8080,создал connect test,в нем все проходит удачно и без ошибок,но когда пытаюсь подключиться к http://ExternalIP:8080,ничего не получается,бесконечная загрузка,проверял /etc/usr/jenkins файл,там все четка без ошибок,пробовал в него добавлять

```
HTTP_HOST=0.0.0.0
HTTP_PORT=8080
HTTPS_HOST=0.0.0.0
HTTPS_PORT=443
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Подскажите как починить,нужно чтобы подключалось без ошибок
Не актуально,снес все и заново поставил - заработало

Comment: А не может быть очевидого - дженкинс видит, что к нему идут по несекьюрному HTTP, и выдаёт вам код 302 - редирект на HTTPS? А HTTPS то вы наружу не открывали.... А воообе самое простое - это поднять nginx, котрый хостит статитку, и сначала проверить, что работает "просто сайт", а потом на место этого сайта засунуть денкинса. Так сказать, разделить проблему на две

Comment: Можете по подробнее объяснить как использовать nginx,впервые в жизни работаю с ubuntu и не понимаю как это может помочь в решении моей проблемы.

Answer (score 0):

У нас с автором вопроса завязалась переписка в комментариях, я решил написать ответ, так как в нем, по меньшей мере, больше возможносей форматирования.

Изложу свою идею.

К сожалению, я не могу - без особенного приложения сил - воспроизвести Вашу конфигурацию. Но мой взгляд зацепился за фразу "добавил firewall rule для tcp:8080".

Дальше я рассуждаю так: сейчас практически не осталось сайтов, которые работали бы по http, все работают по https. Вы ни слова не написали о том, что порт для https распаблишен, и на той картинке, которая приложена к вопросу, видно обратное.

Поэтому предланаю сделать шаг 0) распаблишить тот же набор портов, который в конфиге.

Следующими шагами может быть проверка того, что я прав - что всё работает через https. Для этого достаточно "локально" открыть дженкинс - ну, короче, тот сайт, который вы подняли - и посмотреть в адресную строку браузера.

А nginx я предложил поднять "сгоряча" - как самый простой веб-сервер, который легко настраивать. Хотя, конечно, в одну строчку в питончике он поднимается еще проще.